# $_POST array not getting updated after consecutive form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, button, printing

Here is a form made in HTML. It also prints the $_POST variable in the same page. Anyone implementing this program would want that the values inside $_POST are from the form from the current submit press. What is actually happening is that even after pressing the submit button for an empty form the previous array is being printed. I am applying server side validation by checking empty fields from the $_POST array and then flashing error messages for them. This is why I am sending the empty form. The first thing that I need to do is let the $_POST variable carry the entries from the last submit. Please suggest where have I made the mistake. The HTML, CSS and the PHP codes are appended. The HTML and CSS code snippets are pasted in separate boxes. The PHP code is written alongwith. Also that I have not attached the entire HTML code. As the file is about 9-10 pages only the relevant HTML portion is attached. [$_POST printing with form

```css
<style>
    .required:after{
        content:" *";
        color: red;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .header{
        padding: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1abc9c;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .input-element{
        height:26px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    
    .button {
        background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
        
    .nav-item, nav-link{
        color:blue;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .nav-item:hover, nav-link:hover, nav-item:focus, nav-item:focus{
        color:red
    }
    
    </style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>School form</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  </head>
    
  <body>
  <form name="myForm" action="index.php" method="POST" >      
  class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div>
                        <label style="font-size:14px" class = "required" for="Admission Type">प्रवेश प्रकार(Admission Type)</label>
                        
                        <select id="AdmissionType" name="AdmissionType" placeholder ="Admission Type" required class="input-element">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                        <?php
                        include 'variables.php';
                        
                        foreach($fields['AdmissionType'] as $item){
                            echo "<option value='".$item."' style='font-size:14px'>".$item."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div>
                    <label  style="font-size:14px"class="required">नामांकन संख्या(Enrollment Number)</label>
                    
                    <input type="text" id = "EnrollmentNumber" name="EnrollmentNumber" required placeholder = "Enter Enrollment Number" class="input-element">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div>
                    <label  style="font-size:14px"class="required">ईमेल आईडी (Email Id)</label>
                    
                    <input type="text" id = "EmailId" name="EmailId" required placeholder = "Enter Email Id" style="font-size:14px">
                    
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div>
                        <label style="font-size:14px" for="Course" class="required">पाठ्यक्रम()Course</label>
                        <select name="Course" required placeholder="Course" class="input-element">
                        <option value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
                        <?php
                        include 'variables.php';
                        
                        foreach($fields['Course'] as $item){
                            echo "<option value='".$item."' style='font-size:14px'>".$item."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div>
                    <label style="font-size:14px" for="Exam" class="required">परीक्षा(Exam)</label>
                    <select name="Exam" required placeholder="Select Exam" class="input-element">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <?php
                        include 'variables.php';
                        
                        foreach($fields['Exam'] as $item){
                            echo "<option value='".$item."' style='font-size:14px'>".$item."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
      <input type="submit" name="buttonsubmit" class="button" style="left:50%" value="SUBMIT">
        </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iM8R.png)

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
?>

<?php
    if($_POST['buttonsubmit']= "submit"){
            if($_POST['AdmissionType'] == ""){
                echo "Serverside Validation : Admission Type left empty";
            }   
        }
?>
```

Comment: `if($_POST['buttonsubmit']= "submit")` - that's an assignment, not a comparison. But that should not have much to do with the problem you are describing here. There is no logical reason why it should behave like that. Can only assume that there must be something else going on in the parts you have not shown us.

Comment: this is a relevant correction that you have pointed out. As you have said it is not resolving the issue. I can edit the question to paste the complete code. But I can't find that option yet.

Comment: You aren't using the browser's refresh button to resubmit the form or anything silly like that?

Comment: Thank you for checking that ADyson. Fortunately so, I am present enough not to do that.

Comment: Immediately within the `form` you have `class="container">` presumably that is a `DIV` element? Also - no need to include the `variables.php` script multiple times

Comment: you have css files - why use the nasty inline `style` attributes? That just makes your life harder

Comment: yes the inline style attribute is a lengthy approach

Comment: I have used  websites to understand the code. I miss out on how the container helps. But it should be the <div> element.

Is it so that I can pass the array by using variables.php only once. Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed your posted data saved in your form after submission or in an error case and you do not want to return an empty array.

you can use the below snippet for a better understanding

```html
<?php

// Init Default Array with blank values
$post_data = array('inputname_1'=>'','inputname_2'=>'',...'inputname_n'=>'');

if($_POST){
    $post_data = $_POST;
 // Here your post code
}

?>

<html>

<form name="myForm" action="index.php" method="POST">
 <input name="inputname_1" value="<?=$post_data['inputname_1']?>">
 <input name="inputname_2" value="<?=$post_data['inputname_2']?>">
 ...
 <input name="inputname_n" value="<?=$post_data['inputname_n']?>">
 <input type="submit" name="buttonsubmit" class="button" style="left:50%" value="SUBMIT">      
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Chirayu. I could understand the code of yours. But I am having difficulty in knowing its relevance. Can you help me walk through.

Comment: Hey, Arpit You need to put your input fields name into the given array $post_data 
Please change your code as below:
$post_data = array('AdmissionType'=>'','EnrollmentNumber'=>'','Exam'=>'','EmailId'=>'','CourseId'=>'' );

and in <form> ...</form> too change value attributes of input fields